# button animation breaking on rapid button click

Tags: javascript, css

i have a simple button that scales up and returns back to normal on click :

```
let timeoutId = null;

    const btnAnimation = (e, size) => {
        const button = e.currentTarget;

        button.style.transform = `scale(${size})`;

        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }

        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            button.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
        }, 300);
    };
```

i'm calling it with simple on:click(svelte syntax). problem is when someone rapid clicks it it always stays scaled Up. and only on last click is the animation played.

i tried adding:

```
button.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
```

inside the `if(timeout)` , or anywhere else basically but it breaks it even more. i don't want to disable the button so is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your modified javascript (i have made a comment of what i added)

```js
let timeoutId = null;

function btnAnimation(e) {
  const size = 1.2;
  const button = e;

  //We check if the animation is actualy playing, 
  //if true we give time (ScaleDelay) to the button to return to scale(1) state; 
  //if not we start the animating without delay
  var ScaleDelay = 0;
  if (button.style.transform != 'scale(1)') {
    button.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    ScaleDelay = 50;
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    button.style.transform = `scale(${size})`;
  }, ScaleDelay);


  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }

  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    button.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
  }, 300);
};
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: transform 50ms;
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Buttons - "Pressed Effect"</h2>

<button class="button" onclick="btnAnimation(this)">Click Me</button>
```

If you want you can do a similar (but better in my opinion) effect with CSS only :

```css
.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: scale(1);
   transition : transform 100ms;
}

.button:hover {background-color: cyan}

.button:active {
  transition : transform 0ms;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Buttons - "Pressed Effect"</h2>

<button class="button">Click Me</button>
```